# Make elements in UITableVew Custom cell touchable

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib, custom-cell

I have a UITableView with custom cell XIB. The custom cell has two labels and one UITextView. It all works fine, however I noticed that when I press on the labels or the UITextView, nothing happens. Its only when I press an area of the cell which is not covered by the labels or the UITextView that the cell will respond.

How can I make the cell respond to anything that is touched in the cell?

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: labels are not touchable by default. but textfeild should get clicked. Have you added any other view over cell? Give some code

Comment: Thanks @Durgaprasad - I completely forgot about the interaction option in Interface builder. Problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah basically I forgot to select the interaction option in Interface Builder. lol...